# Directional derivative Given maximum point problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> Given the function $f(x,y,z)$ a function that has continuous partial derivatives in $R^3$ . Also given two directions : $u=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$ and $v=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0)$.
> Out of all the directional derivatives at point $P$ the maximum value is $\sqrt{12}$ when the derivative is done at direction $u$ . find the value of the directional derivative of the function at point P in direction $v$

The directions given are unit vectors , Also given the maximum value means that $||\nabla||=\sqrt{12}$ because out of all the directional derivatives at a given point , when we are at the direction of the gradient we get the max value.
$\nabla f=(f_x,f_y,f_z)$ but since there is no actual function I cannot find the partial derivatives and assuming that point $P$ is $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ then the directional derivative in direction $v$ should be $D_{v}f=\nabla f \cdot v$ but I cannot see how this will help and I got stuck cannot find a way to continue.

I know that it seems that I did not try enough but I really did try all that I know and I am just looking for tips for the question no solution.

thank you appreciate all the tips and help

Edit: I tried $D_uf$ and got $D_uf=f_x \cdot (\frac{1}{\sqrt3})+f_y \cdot (\frac{1}{\sqrt3})+f_z \cdot (-\frac{1}{\sqrt3})$ and since  $||\nabla||=\sqrt{12}$ I got $f_x+f_y-f_z=6$  and also $D_vf=f_x \cdot (\frac{1}{\sqrt2})+f_y \cdot (\frac{1}{\sqrt2})+0$ , $D_vf=\frac{f_x+f_y}{\sqrt2}$ this felt like a lead but I don't know how it will help me so I guess its useless

Comment: The direction $u$ along which the maximum directional derivative occurs will also be the direction of the gradient, whose magnitude will be the maximum value. So the directional derivative along $v$ will be $\nabla f \cdot \hat{v}$ but we know that $\nabla f$ is $\sqrt{12}\hat{u}$, so...

Comment: @Benjamin_Gal thank you for the help , but can you please try to explain a bit more what you mean?

Comment: If we accept that fact that by definition $\nabla f = \sqrt{12}\hat{u}$, then $D_v f = \nabla f \cdot \hat{v} = \sqrt{12}(\hat{u} \cdot \hat{v})$, the dot product can be easily computed.

Comment: @Benjamin_Gal perfect , thank you